# Fastest way to move first element to the end of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I'm wondering what is the fastest way in JavaScript to move an element from the beginning of an `Array` to the end. For example if we have

`[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

And we want: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

I want to move the first element to the end. I was thinking about switching element 0 with element 1, after that switching element 1 with element 2 and so on until the 8 is at the and (basically how bubblesort works). I was wondering if there is a faster way to bring the first element to the end.

I will be using small Arrays (around 10 elements), and I want to avoid `shift()` since it's pretty slow.

This is what I have now on chrome it's 45% faster than normal shift+push: http://jsperf.com/shift-myfunc

The arrays will have objects in them for a game.

Comment: It's a shame how OP is looking for the _fastest_ way and not just _a_ and people are giving general answers without explaining why they're faster/slower than alternatives. FGITW I guess. OP, what is your specific use case? What browsers are you targeting? How big is the array (are they always ~8 elements? Are they 10K elements?), if you want real benchmarking you need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Thanks for editing to clarify - next round: are they arrays sparse like `[1,2,,,5,8]` or are they _always_ full (like your example), do they always contain integers only? What browsers/engines are you targeting and how many iterations of these sort of shifts do you need to do per second at most?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It would have helped if the OP would have stated what they tried up front and maybe there would not have been general answers. Effort in question = effort in answer. Simple tests with JSPerf would on been nice. :)

Comment: @epascarello True - the _fastest_ way to do something is very dependent here- on the target JS engine, on the array size, on what it contains and so on - I'm also still waiting to be convinced OP really needs it to be that fast and at what expense (if he is rotating a lot for example it might be good to keep a copy of the array concatenated to itself and slice it, work with a typed array or use other useful tricks). I know _you_ and j08691 are definitely good guys around here from knowing a bunch of your other answer but answering one just seemed kind of pointless given the ambiguity.

Answer (score 133):

**Use the shift() and push() functions:**

```
var ary = [8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
ary.push(ary.shift());  // results in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Example:

```js
var ary = [8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

console.log("Before: " + ary);

ary.push(ary.shift());  // results in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 

console.log("After: " + ary);
```

Comment: For any future bypassers, how this works is using the Shift function. It removes the first item in an array and then returns it.
So in other words, this code removes the first item in the array and then adds it again - making it go to the bottom of the array.

Comment: very well done... I was looking for the opposite but came up on this answer so after some quick research here is the opposite way of doing the above... ary.unshift(ary.pop());

Answer (score 26):

Use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
var a = ["a","b","c"];
var b = a.shift();
a.push(b);
```

or

```
var b = a.shift();
a[a.length] = b;
```

---

### Edit Based on updated question

What is going to be the fastest? Really depends on content of the array and what browser/version!

**Now what are the ways to remove the first index?**

- `shift()`
- `splice()`
- `slice()`

**Now what are the ways to add to the last index?**

- `push()`
- `array[array.length]`
- `concat()` -- not even going to try

**Other ways**

- for loop - make new array [going to be horrible on large arrays]

**JSPerf:**

http://jsperf.com/test-swapping-of-first-to-last

---

**What is really the fastest?**

What is the fastest really depends on what you are doing with the array. If you are just using the first index, it will be fastest just to make your code read an index and not shift the values. If you are using all the indexes, than just loop and through and when you get to the end start back at zero. Basic counters.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the use of shift since it's pretty slow.

Comment: Than say that in your question!

Comment: @user2815780 - Perhaps you should post what you've already tried in your question, including stats to show what's fast and slow?

Comment: I updated my answer with ways to do it and a JSPerf. I am sure my loop answer can be improved, I just threw it together as a break from my real work.

Comment: note that splice() returns an array so the test called "splice-push" (my personal preference) is not 100% correct. Should be:      `var b = arr.splice(0, 1);
arr.push(b[0]);`

Answer (score 18):

And here is a sweet ES6 version

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

const [first, ...rest] = arr;
arr = [...rest,first]
```

Comment: That really is sweet

Answer (score 9):

Use splice to get the first element

```
var first = array.splice(0,1);
```

Then push to make if the last.

Since the return value of the splice method is an array, you have to say

```
array.push(first[0]);
```

Working example here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Uha/2/)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you want to put any element to the end:

```
var ary = [8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
ary.push(ary.splice(position, 1)[0]);
```

for  `position` just wrap this in a forEach.

Comment: `ary.push(ary.slice(position, 1));` is wrong and would result in `[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,Array[1]` if position was 0, or `[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,Array[0]` if position was 1. I assume you wanted `splice` rather than `slice`. Cause `slice` doesn't remove items, and it uses the arg list `start, end` rather than `start, deleteCount`. Either way, both slice/splice return an Array, so you have to push the first item of the arr, rather than the arr itself.

I fixed the code: `ary.push(ary.splice(0, 1)[0]);`

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var b= a[7];
var c = a.slice(1, 8);
c.push(b);
```

**Edit:** It's probably better to just shift, like epascarello did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385816/how-to-bring-first-element-of-array-to-the-end-js#answer-20385882).

Answer (score 3):

With ES20...

```
const newArr = [
   ...arr.slice(1),
   arr[0]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

> one more flavour

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr = arr.concat(arr.shift())
```

> concat can add not just a element but another array at the end or beginning

Answer (score 0):

Updating the arrays moving elements from one extreme to the other:

```js
const array = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];

const next = [...array]
next.push(next.shift())
console.log(next); // [ 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'First' ]

const prev = [...array]
prev.unshift(prev.pop())
console.log(prev); // [ 'Fourth', 'First', 'Second', 'Third' ]
```